# recaptcha validation API returns always true

Tags: recaptcha

I am using google's recaptcha test setup (Site key: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI) but always get returned success: true..

My python code is straight forward I guess

```
challenge = event["body"]

data = {
    'secret': "6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe", ##google's generic secret
    'response' : challenge
}

captcha_verify_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";

r = requests.get(captcha_verify_url, params=data)
```

I can send whatever and to get:
{
"success": true,
"challenge_ts": "2021-01-08T13:07:54Z",
"hostname": "testkey.google.com"
}

Is that a normal behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is perfectly normal behaviour designed for automated testing.
[recaptcha-docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do)

Comment: Please use hyperlink formatting in place of directly pasting the link.